# golang: 32-bit access to mmap'd "/dev/mem" region

Tags: go

Since golang is a systems language, it should be capable of doing some user space hardware driver job then.

I want to mmap "/dev/mem" and do some read or writes to some memory mapped pci registers.
Since golang's syscall.Mmap return a byte array. How could I possibly do a 32-bit(for example) read or writes to the registers?

byte by byte access is not approperiate since some registers only support 32 bit access.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `unsafe` and getting a `*uint32` pointer into the block at the right offset. Here's an example for a regular byte array, but an mmap'ed one should work the same.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := make([]byte, 30)
    p := (*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&a[8]))
    *p = 0xabcd0123
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. You are welcome. ;)

```
func Readu32(baseAddress int64, offset int64) uint32 {
        var value uint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        const bufferSize int = 4096

        file, err := os.Open("/dev/mem")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer file.Close()
        mmap, err := syscall.Mmap(int(file.Fd()), baseAddress, bufferSize, syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_SHARED)

        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        value = *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap[offset]))
        err = syscall.Munmap(mmap)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        return value
}
```

Comment: And how to write?